# How to save the style of the ribbon?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using the Ribbon component in Delphi XE2. In my application I allow to change the style of the Ribbon, and also change the position of the `QuickAccesToolbar`.

Change the style TRibbon with the following code:

```
     1: Ribbon.Style: = RibbonObsidianStyle;
```

But to close the program and re-enter the Ribbon loses the value of the style property in style and appears by default. How do I get the style property of the Ribbon to be saved? 
How to make to save the position of the `QuickAccesToolbar` and actions user have been aggregated into "More Commands"?

Comment: Save the settings to a user config file or the registry. Just like any other user customisation.

Comment: Save the style is easy, but I can not find a way to keep the buttons in the ribbon 

I did something like that where I am saving the nombreas of shares in the Windows registry: 

for vI: = 0 to -1 do vRibbon.QuickAccessToolbar.ActionBar.Items.Count 
begin 
  GuardarInfoReg (vPathReg + '\ fKiPrincipal', 'ToolbarBoton' +    IntToStr (vI),''); 
end; 

What I need now from the names of the reload action in the toolbar cienta options to enter the program